# PHP + CSS + Lettering.js Creating curved text

Tags: php, css, geometry, typography

I'm using lettering.js to wrap `<span>` elements around each letter in a string. I'm getting the string using PHP. In the example below, `$bellcurve` is not yet defined-- the example is the approach I imagine might get me to a solution, but really I'm not sure if this is the right way (but that's the question).

So given that:

```
$string = "Hey!! Don't be an apple!"
```

I want to count the characters in that string, then for each character, create a class declaration as shown below, with each value for "top" resulting in an overall bell shape.

My PHP knowledge gets me this far:

```
    $string = "Hey!! Don't be an apple!";
    $string = str_split($string);
    $i = 1;
    foreach($string as $char){
        echo '.char' . $i . '{top: ' . $bellcurve * $i . 'px}';
        $i++;
    }
```

For example, a quick try at this done manually looks like this:

```
span.char1 {top: 20px}
span.char2 {top: 18px}
span.char3 {top: 16px}
span.char4 {top: 15px}
span.char5 {top: 14px}
span.char6 {top: 13px}
span.char7 {top: 12px}
span.char8 {top: 11px}
span.char9 {top: 10px}
span.char10 {top: 10px}
span.char11 {top: 10px}
span.char12 {top: 9px}
span.char13 {top: 9px}
span.char14 {top: 10px}
span.char15 {top: 10px}
span.char16 {top: 10px}
span.char17 {top: 11px}
span.char18 {top: 12px}
span.char19 {top: 13px}
span.char20 {top: 14px}
span.char21 {top: 15px}
span.char22 {top: 16px}
span.char23 {top: 18px}
span.char24 {top: 20px}
```

What I need to know how to do is create a coefficient ( `$bellcurve` ) which, when multiplied by $i (the character index), will create a bell curve when iterated over the total number of characters.

Or if there is a better approach, please let me know!

Thanks!

---

Here is the answer converted to PHP from javascript:

```
<?php
        $string = get('character_slogan');
        $string = str_split($string);
        $count = count($string);
        $pi = pi();
        $c = 1.0;
        $b = $count / 2;
        $piece = sqrt(2*$pi);
        $a = 1 / ($c*$piece);
?>

    <style type="text/css">

<?php 
    $x = 1;
    foreach($string as $char){
        $E = M_E;
        $bellcurve = ($a*$E)-(pow($x-$b, 2)/pow(2*$c, 2));
        echo '.char' . $x . '{top: ' . -$bellcurve . 'px}
        ';
        $x++;
    }
?>
    </style>
```

Comment: What are you having problems with? Counting the chars? Adding spans to them?

Comment: Provide a link when it's done - I wonder what it looks like! It's not too difficult, but I'm too lazy right now :P

Comment: @wrikken I've clarified the question a little more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Gaussian function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function) to create a curve resembling a "bell curve"

[image]

I'm setting up a, b, c like so:

```
a = 1/(1.0*(Math.sqrt(2*Math.PI))) // height of the curve's peak ( 1/(σ√(2π)) )
b = letterCount / 2                // position of the center, b = μ (expected value)
c = 1.0                            // width of the "bell", c = σ (variance)
```

then iterating over the `span` elements and getting the `top` "bellPosition" like so

```
bellPosition = (a*Math.E)-(Math.pow(x-b, 2)/Math.pow(2*c, 2))
```

you can play with this (especially c to change the variance in the curve)

**[this example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/Zk7b2/)** uses javascript to apply the `top` styles to the `span` elements, should be easy enough to translate to PHP.

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I was looking for. I've added the PHP version at the bottom of my answer. 

Supposing I wanted to extend the effect by rotating the letters in the shape of the curve, so that the the angle of the last letter is the positive value of the angle of the first letter, and the middle letter has an angle of 0. I think this would be more like a SIN wave... Do you know what function would achieve that?

Thanks again!

Comment: @j-man86 came across this js library and remembered this question, check out [Arctext.js](http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/), it does letters in the shape of the curve (and other effects)

Answer (score 0):

i've found this solution very quickly, use str_split to split word into chars and then you can use this to find median:

crescentfreshpot at yahoo dot com 27-Jul-2005 02:50
Median:

number median ( number arg1, number arg2 [, number ...] )

number median ( array numbers )

this function is from http://php.net/manual/en/ref.math.php and user crescentfreshpot at yahoo dot com 27-Jul-2005 02:50

Comment: This doesn't really help him. He's not trying to find the median value of an array of numbers.

Answer (score -2):

I will have a look at this in detail when I get home from work.
For now, the following should get you started:

add the following attributes to your style to position the characters:

```
<span style="display:inline-block; position:absolute; top:$Y; left:$x;">$z</span>
```

increase $X to display your characters on a horizontal line and increase / decrease $Y to change the vertical position.
TO create the desired bell shape, increase / decrease $Y by a incrementally lesser / bigger number everytime, depending if you are before or after the middle of the word.

Comment: Thanks Erik, but the question is not how to use absolute positioning in CSS, it's how to create the css positioning automatically with a php function, given any string.

Comment: You would split up your words into an array of letters using substr() strlen() and a for loop, then iterate through the array of letters and display them using the code line I posted above.
If you want me to write out all the code for you, just ask.